# the memory location of static and extern storage class in C

Tags: c, static, compiler-errors, declaration, extern

I have two files which are sharing the global variables.

In main.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
static int b;
extern int b;
main()
{
extern int a;
printf("a=%d &a:%p\n",a,&a);
printf("b=%d &b:%p\n",b,&b);
fn();
}
```

In fun.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int b=25;
int a=10;
fn()
{
printf("in fna=%d &a:%p\n",a,&a);
printf("in fnb=%d &b:%p\n",b,&b);
}
```

If I compile both files. I'm not getting any compilation error. And its fine.The output is

`a=10 &a:0x804a018
b=0 &b:0x804a024
in fna=10 &a:0x804a018
in fnb=25 &b:0x804a014`

But, in main.c if I alter the lines `extern int b` and `static int b` like this

```
#include<stdio.h>
extern int b;
static int b;
main()
{
extern int a;
printf("a=%d &a:%p\n",a,&a);
printf("b=%d &b:%p\n",b,&b);
fn();
}
```

At compilation, I'm getting this error.

`main.c:6:12: error: static declaration of ‘b’ follows non-static declaration
main.c:5:12: note: previous declaration of ‘b’ was here`

Here the issue is with memory at which static and extern variables are stored. But I couldn't able to conclude the exact reason why is the compilation error at second time

Note: I'm using gcc compiler.

Comment: And the question is? You should split the question into the reason for the compiler error and the allocation strategy of the compiler for specific variables.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to write `static int a;`!

Comment: Please look into this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14403796/can-a-variable-be-declared-both-static-and-extern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two quotes from the C Standard (6.2.2 Linkages of identifiers) will help to understand the problem.

> 4 For an identifier declared with the storage-class specifier extern
>   in a scope in which a prior declaration of that identifier is
>   visible,31) if the prior declaration specifies internal or external
>   linkage, the linkage of the identifier at the later declaration is the
>   same as the linkage specified at the prior declaration. If no prior
>   declaration is visible, or if the prior declaration specifies no
>   linkage, then the identifier has external linkage.

and

> 7 If, within a translation unit, the same identifier appears with both
>   internal and external linkage, the behavior is undefined.

In this translation unit

```
#include<stdio.h>
static int b;
extern int b;
main()
{
extern int a;
printf("a=%d &a:%p\n",a,&a);
printf("b=%d &b:%p\n",b,&b);
fn();
}
```

indentifier `b` has internal linkage (read the first quote).
The first declaration of `b` declares the identifier as  having the internal linkage due to the storage-calss specifier `static`. The second declaration of **b** with the storage-class specifier `extern` has prior declaration of `b` (the first declaration) with the the storage class specifier `static`. So the linkage of the identifer is the same as the linkage of the prior declared identifier.

In this translation unit

```
#include<stdio.h>
extern int b;
static int b;
main()
{
extern int a;
printf("a=%d &a:%p\n",a,&a);
printf("b=%d &b:%p\n",b,&b);
fn();
}
```

identifier `b` is declared as having external and internal linkage (read the both quotes). So the compiler issues the message.

At first the identifier `b` was declared as having external linkage (because there is no prior declaration with a given linkage) And then due to the specifier `static` the same identifier is declared as having internal linkage.