# Can a variable be both static and extern

Tags: c

I was asked this

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int a;
extern int a;//

int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

I said I will refrain from writing such things in a code, whatever the use case (because I really had no idea).

Later I told that it should be a compilation error as static makes a to live only while this file runs,
extern makes it seem that **a** can live outside of this scope, that is contradictory.
This program compiled.

1. Where I am wrong?
2. What would be your answer?
3. What is the use case if its legal?

Comment: As far as I know `static` and `extern` are used almost to achieve "opposite" results.

Comment: I was asked if the program will compile or not. I said it should not compile. later I checked and it compiled.

Comment: You can declare as `extern` a variable that is also defined in the current compilation unit. It says to the compiler that the variable is defined somewhere else, in case it cannot find its definition in the current compilation unit. It is a hint, not an enforcement.

Comment: The warning: `a is defined but not used` has nothing to do with `extern` and `static`. `a` is simply not used. if you put `printf("%d\n", a);` into `main`, the warning should go away.

Comment: It's legal. See ISO/IEC-9899:2011 §6.2.2 para 4: "For an identifier declared with the storage-class specifier extern in a scope in which a prior declaration of that identifier is visible,31) if the prior declaration specifies internal or external linkage, the linkage of the identifier at the later declaration is the same as the linkage specified at the prior declaration. If no prior declaration is visible, or if the prior declaration specifies no linkage, then the identifier has external linkage." Footnote 31 says "As specified in 6.2.1, the later declaration might hide the prior declaration."

Comment: Nothing from the document or that duplicate answer makes sense. It looks like people want other people to be confused all the time. In the answer given in the other thread says when you declare static in a;extern int a; the linkage is internal. Why there is no conflict of linkages because extern is for extern linkage?

Comment: At the same time shamelessly says extern int a;static int a; there is a linkage confict. Wth if it was  not a problem in first case why can't compiler decide in this case too?make it internal

Comment: @acidlategamer Because the standard says so. See netcoders answer in the dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14404244/646887   I agree that this is a language-lawyer type question and the OP:s instinct to never do like this is very sound.

Comment: Regarding item 3 of your question, here is a flimsily contrived example: `int foo(void) { extern int a; return 2 * a; }`. The function `foo` returns twice the value of variable `a` that is declared before the function. The function does not care whether the variable `a` has internal (`static`) or external linkage, as long as it has type `int`. The simpler function `int foo(void) { return 2 * a; }` does not check the type of external variable `a`.