# Can we declare a file scope identifier with internal linkage without the static keyword?

Tags: c

Section 6.11.2 of the C standard states one of the features that may be deprecated in future versions:

> Declaring an identifier with internal linkage at file scope without
>   the static storage-class specifier is an obsolescent feature.

How is it even possible to declare a file scope identifier to have internal linkage without the static storage-class specifier?

Comment: maybe like this? `int a; int func(){extern int a;`

Comment: Simply by having a visible identifier with internal linkage at the point of a file scope declaration using the `extern` keyword (here the linkage is inhered from that visible identifier). Or another case I can think of (which I'm not 100% sure) is when you have an `inline` function - because `inline` functions are by default declared with internal linkage (correct me here if I'm wrong).

Comment: Which C standard?

Answer (score 2):

There is a specific example for this issue in the C++ standard.
In [dcl.stc]:

```
static int b; // b has internal linkage
extern int b; // b still has internal linkage
```

So in the second line, b is declared as a file scope identifier with internal linkage without the keyword static.
The example is also true for C, as C11:6.2.2 says:

> For an identifier declared with the storage-class specifier extern in a scope in which a prior declaration of that identifier is visible, if the prior declaration specifies internal or external  linkage,  the  linkage  of  the  identifier  at  the  later  declaration  is  the  same  as  the linkage specified at the prior declaration.  If no prior declaration is visible, or if the prior declaration specifies no linkage, then the identifier has external linkage.

[see this question for more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14403796/can-a-variable-be-declared-both-static-and-extern)